# C#: Is it possible to position a 2darray in a certain position in another 2darray without iterating through it?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to position a 2d array in a certain position in another 2d array without iterating through it?

```
public double[,] array2D;
array2D = new double[7,7];

public void fill1D(double[,] values) 
{
   Array2D = values; //Values holds a 5x5 array that i wan't to place from 1,1 in array2D
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't (edit: without copying) , I'm sorry. You could mimic this perhaps with the `ArraySegement` (but you'd have to use a 1D base array. You may also care to read  [this paper](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/papers/numericperformance.pdf) that suggests plain rectangular arrays are relatively slow in C#.

Comment: However the conclusion stated, that nothing in general could be said sbout array handling in c#, as far as i understood.